# Libraries to parse SAS SPDE in R?

Tags: r

Apologies for asking a question that is basically a search, but so far my efforts looking into this have not turned up much.

We're working with some data that has been organized into chunks with `SPDE` partitioning using `SAS 9`, but we're looking to see if this same data can be read from within the `R` framework.

I have seen that `SASPy` can do this with the right calls, and that the `haven` package from the `tidyverse` can handle some `SAS` formats (e.g. `sas7bdat`), but my fear is that given this is a proprietary organizational scheme, there are no out-of-the-box packages or solutions for pulling this data into `R` that doesn't involve converting it into a different format (e.g. `parquet` or similar) via `SAS` or `SASPy` first and then moving it into `R`.

Was hoping to see if anyone had come across or utilized anything of this nature in their own work, as the documentation and help for the packages I have explored have not turned up much.

Thank you to all in advance!